# Excel 2010 VBA.. Adding series to existing chart

Tags: excel, vba

I am currently trying to populate a chart with data where the user can simply press the button on the spreadsheet. The issue I am having is I need the button to copy data to a data sheet and then the chart will populate from the data sheet. I can do this, but I need a new series created on the chart for every new data that is ente

```
Sub RoundedRectangle2_Click()

End Sub


Sub MAPS()
Sheets("MAPS_FORM").Range("e47").Copy
Sheets("Data_Sheet").Range("b65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial _
Paste:=xlPasteValues
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Sheets("MAPS_FORM").Range("d2").Copy
Sheets("Data_Sheet").Range("a65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial _
Paste:=xlPasteValues
Application.CutCopyMode = False



Sheets("Data_Sheet").Range("b2:b46").Copy
Charts("Chart1").SeriesCollection.Paste

Range("e6:i8").ClearContents
Range("e12:i19").ClearContents
Range("e23:i27").ClearContents
Range("e31:i36").ClearContents
Range("e40:i43").ClearContents
Range("d2").ClearContents
Sheets("Data_Sheet").Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply change the `.SetSourceData` property after you add the data.

Let's take an example

Lets say you data is from `A1:A5` and the chart is based on that range. See screenshot below

[image]

Now lets say your added data is from `B1:B5` and want that to show as a series in the chart then simply use this code

```
Option Explicit

'~~> Please amend the code as applicable
Sub Sample()
    Dim objChrt As ChartObject
    Dim chrt As Chart

    Set objChrt = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1")
    Set chrt = objChrt.Chart

    With chrt
        .SetSourceData (ActiveSheet.Range("A1:B5"))
    End With
End Sub
```

When you run the code the chart will automatically show the new series.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'll have to check it out and try it on Monday to see if I can get it to work for me.

Comment: What i am looking to do is every time the button is clicked a new set of data is copied into the Data_Sheet which is then entered into the chart as a new series based on the series name being the date and the series data point being a number.

Comment: That's what the code does. simply change the `SetSourceData` after you enter th new data in the sheet.

Comment: So this code needs to be in it's own module? Forgive my ignorance I don't work too much with VBA and most of my experience is trial and error.

Comment: Lets say you add the data to Col C then your sourcedata in the above code will become `A1:C5`

Comment: I have not been able to get it to work with your method. I am sure it works great, but since I don't really understand too much I have made some changes to my original code. The new code does almost everything I want except to assign the series "name" along with the data. The series "name" is the date that the information is entered the range is A2:A46. The data set is B2:B46. As of now the chart updates a new series with the data set, but I can't for the life of me figure how to attribute the series name from A2:A46. It is probably something easy.

Comment: What I was saying can be easily shown with this... You are copying the range and then using `Charts("Chart1").SeriesCollection.Paste` to populate the series. As per my exammple, all you had to do was `Charts("Chart1").SetSourceData Source:=Sheets("Data_Sheet").Range("B2:B46")` instead of copying and pasting :) Now regarding your query what did you mean by `attribute the series name from A2:A46`

Comment: In the cells A2:A46 the date of the data entered is displayed. So I need the Series name to equal the date.

Comment: `Dim MyNewSrs As Series
    Set MyNewSrs = Charts("Chart1").SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    With MyNewSrs
    .Name = "=Data_Sheet!A2:A46"
    .Values = "=Data_Sheet!B2:B46"
    End With` This seems to work, but the series name becomes